# How do you load an existing data project in EF 6.2 with database first methodology into a Web API Core2 Controller?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

So I have an EF application that is working great but it is thick client and I wanted to go service based and use Azure and MS's Core 2 framework.  I go to build the Web API out of the box.  Test it works, it does great.  Now let's add a reference to my DataAccess Library that uses EF, bombs out.  Oops forgot to add EF to new project through NuGet, do that.  It proceeds to tell me it cannot find my reference to the connection string.  Okay so I wire up it in the appsettings.json to a local instance database like so (copying from what works in a WPF client project already):

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ExpensesEntities": "metadata=res://*/Expenses.csdl|res://*/Expenses.ssdl|res://*/Expenses.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=Expenses;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
  }
}
```

And I change my startup like so:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddScoped(_ => new MoneyEntry.DataAccess.ExpensesEntities());
}
```

I can see it attempt to get to my context and break saying

```
 'FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, 
  Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. 
  The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

Yet it's breaking on this section of the EF Context

```
public ExpensesEntities()
        : base("name=ExpensesEntities")
    {
    }
```

So I am pretty sure I just need to have the reference for the connection string in the right order and I goofed in where I put the connection string or some type of loading of the config.  I was following this thread: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings

My other concern is can I mix EF Frameworks?  I wrote my Data Access Layer in EF 6.1.3 I just upgraded to 6.2 and yet I know .NET Core has it's own libraries.  Can I mix EF.NET Core with EF.NET Framework?  Or should I try to rewrite my DAL in Core too?  Whatever it is, it appears to not like it and I may just try to see if I can add a model self contained from scratch to see how it works.  But thought I would ask to see if people had experience blending frameworks on the new .NET Core 2.

**EDIT 11-15-17**
Okay so following this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6#handle-connection-strings is a little helpful.  Yet they are doing an MVC site and not an API alone, assuming code first methodology, and also that you want dependency injection.  To simplify can you do this with Database first and just get the appsettings to recognize the EF connection string?  In the past you just make another project, copy and paste your EF section into the new app config, poof it works.  Since ASP.NET Core 2 uses an appsettings I have tried to do a simpler connection string like:

```
"Expenses": "Server=.;Database=Expenses;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

I use one of my simplest tables that only has an Id int property, and a string Description property.  It then bombs on loading the controller when I hit a breakpoint just trying to get the data like so:

```
 var data = await _context.tdType.ToListAsync();
 return View(data);
```

and assumes I need to define a key and am using code first.  Am I assuming that EF Core cannot handle Model first behavior then and I need to adorn POCOs generated with Code first methodology?  If so at this point I may need to recreate my entire EF with code first and consider how to handle procedures and views with it too.

I think the key to understanding this is this model I am using has views, functions, and procedures.  From the little I know of code first you can update the mapping options of a DbSet object to override the Insert, Update, and Delete options.  But the views, functions and procedures that are not directly related to tables but multiple operations are really kind of a mystery.  It may be that EF Core simply is not full featured enough.  But for that reason I thought piggy backing an existing EF 6.2 would fix this.

Comment: No one really even answered the question.  There were lack of specifics and reading on many of the responses parts.  I am not going to willfully give bounty to answers that are not detailed.  If someone wants to say: "Database first won't work", here is an article AND WHY SPECIFICALLY.  I'm fine with that if it MS's position.  But I know for a fact I am getting it to work farther than previously and it is going back to my referenced project in .NET FROM CORE, just fine.  So just hearing: "Try this other tech" or "Just do code first" is really not even attempt at answering the question.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use an EF 6 context in .Net Core directly, from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6):

> You can't put an EF6 context in an ASP.NET Core project because .NET Core projects don't support all of the functionality that EF6 commands such as Enable-Migrations require.

You can however use EF 6 using another assembly:

> The recommended way to use Entity Framework 6 in an ASP.NET Core application is to put the EF6 context and model classes in a class library project that targets the full framework

but do note that it will in effect make you're .Net Core project dependant of the full .Net framework and so it won't be cross platform anymore.

If you're not planning on using .Net core due to the cross platform capabilities and you have invested a lot in your EF 6 code then you might think about creating aps.net full framework web api services so you can rewrite your app from a thick client to a thin client / web api architecture.

Comment: Well a lot of this is really an interest in trying the new method from MS.  Not a mission critical app but more an app I write in my spare time to learn new principles and apply it to.  I am doing what it proposes in the second section already.  It's not working based on getting the connection string.

Comment: Did you added your connection string to appsettings.json?

Comment: So have you or have you not tried a hardcoded connection string as shown in the second code snippet as show [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6#handle-connection-strings)?

Comment: Trying it now I was googling the other day and got this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db.  But that was for EF Core in and of itself, which I don't want at the moment.  Many of the reasons for this is in my reading that EF Core doesn't yet have all the features.  So I may attempt this, then try to refactor to EF Core and see if it works.  I don't want to break my existing Data layer at this point though as I know it works.  And I know that EF Core 2 is claiming it can import full .NET libraries now.

Comment: I will have to play around with the GitHub example they give in this article found as the example from that link: https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/data/entity-framework-6/sample/MVCCore/appsettings.json.  It looks to be the right idea.  I don't like having to use dependency injection to keep an open context though for the life of the controller though.  Generally I always thought to close and dispose with a using block of a context beat into me as connection pools would grow in the past when not doing this in enterprise apps.

Comment: Mine is still getting scrambled up with: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager' even when getting the connection string and adding 'System.Configuration' which holds the ConfigurationManager to the project.  Getting new errors though, so that is good.

Comment: This is basically apples and oranges and is no better than googling what I was already trying.  1. It assumes a code first model.  2. It assumes you are using a non parameter less constructor when before I was doing it parameter less all referencing a base constructor using a connection string and it always worked.  3. It changes the Core 2.0 Framework to use .NET and then the ENTIRE startup looks different than creating a new project right now in VS 2017 for a web api on the configuration and other things.  Mentions this no where in the article.

Answer (score 0):

In short, EF Core 2.1 is not ready for production yet since it doesn't have a lot of major features like:

- many-to-many relationship: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1368
- Lazy loading: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/3797

  ...

We have tried to use EF Core 2.1 on a new project but it doesn't work well for us.
I think you should check the roadmap and issue list carefully:
[Road map](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/wiki/Roadmap) 
[Issue list](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20sort%3Acomments-desc%20-ignore)

Another alternatives is to use OrmLite or Dapper:
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite 
https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper

I know that OrmLite and Dapper aren't what you're looking for, but those are the most stable librarys available for net core right now. We have been done two project, one with dapper and one with OrmLite.
Hope this help.

Comment: You're right, my answer is not what you want. But how about the Paprika you can buy right now is not what you expected, it's bitter?

Comment: Will you continue to cook it, or try so hard, put in to the dish a lot of stuff to remove the bitter taste? Or just use another recipe and have the same result?

Comment: Back to my answer, i think you definitely don't get the limitations of EF Core because you think you can move your whole EF 6.1.2 model to a net core project. That's why i'm talking about the limitation and give you some alternative. I think you should play with EF Core with your real data and decide your next step.

Comment: You are grossly misunderstanding the question and the concept of a reference of something existing versus a refactor of something.

Answer (score -1):

You can create new lib project on classic .net framework with latest EF. After that use case "CodeFirst from Database" for create your entities and dbcontext classes from database. Move you generated code to new .netcore or .netstandart project. Maybe dbcontext will need some changes, add connection string. It works. I did it when i was migrating old-project to new .netcore project. Good luck))

Comment: That is not the question though.  I am curious if there is a limitation that you MUST use code first and cannot use database first or any work around to make it work.  Code first is great until you need to create procedures, views, functions and more.  Then you need to either manually add the script in the migrations or think about a whole new refactor.  I am curious specifically if Database first can be done.

Comment: @djangojazz It's just only small trick to help you to migrate your database structure. Unfortunately and fortunately codeFirst migrations good at development in big team (historicity, more control). In project we created SQL_scripts folder which contains all sqlscripts. And 'code-migrate' can read sql files to execute them. it's another small trick)))

Comment: That is not the problem though.  You are explaining code first and how to do it and I am talking about if a reference to a database first works or not in a whole other project that currently works fine for WPF apps and ASP.NET traditional apps.